# Currently I have two node cluster (SLES as HANA DB). I would like to check in which condition a failover will be triggered?

Tags: suse, sles, bonding, replication, failover

Below are the conditions. We could not test these because these nodes are already in production.

1. Replication between the nodes fail.
2. Replication is working but network link is down with no bonding.
3. Replication is working but one of the NIC in bonding failed.
4. Replication is working but management IP is down.
5. Replication is working but backup IP is down.
6. Replication is working but DB service is stop/restart.
7. Replication working but server shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: The usual method in production is to: 1/ build a preproduction the same way production is built. 2/ test on preproduction